# Jinja2 Environment option "lstrip_blocks" produces TypeError

Tags: jinja2, typeerror, python-3.2

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, python 3.2.3 and jinja2 2.6-1.

When passing the option **lstrip_blocks** to the Environment as follows, I get this error

`"**TypeError: \__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lstrip_blocks'**"`

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('jinja2_hello','.'),lstrip_blocks=True)
template = env.get_template('template_hello.html')
output = template.render()
print(output)
```

The template `template_hello.html` contains only:

```
hello
```

The other option '*trim_blocks*`, alone, works perfectly.

Would you have any suggestions to solve this. I haven't been able to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `lstrip_blocks` option was only added in Jinja 2.7.

Comment: Ok, that explains everything. So I guess that the only solution (without updating to jinja 2.7) for *whitespace control* is to deal with the minus sign, Thanks !